# How to add new instances in existing resource group in Azure via Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform

I would like to add a new VM to existing resource group in Azure which already contains 3 VMs. While running tf apply, it throws an error saying the resource group already exists.

Comment: Please add any relevant code to the question. But based on your query, you would have to import what you already have into terraform state, and then you would be able to add more instances.

Comment: How do I achieve that ?

Comment: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/import

Comment: But it says we can update the resource locally and then apply the changes via Iac. Won't we get the same error saying that the resource group already exists ?

Comment: Yes, you will, but if you don't have anything in terraform, you have to use import or alternatively if there's a resource group data source you can use that, but then all of the other stuff will remain outside of terraform, which is not a good idea.

Comment: I cannot delete existing infra on Azure. I just need to modify it. Is there any other alternative ?

Comment: To refer or create under the existing resource group, using `data` block is an efficient option to achieve. @Shivani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to add a new VM to existing resource group in Azure which already contains 3 VMs. While running tf apply, it throws an error saying the resource group already exists.

If you want to create a **VM** in an existing `resource group` instead of creating a new resource, you can use a data block to import the existing `resource group`.

Here is the updated `Terraform` code for creating 3 resources in an existing **Resource Group**.

```
    provider  "azurerm"  {
      features  {}
    }
    data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
      name = "Existing-RG-Name" 
    }
    
  resource  "azurerm_virtual_network"  "vnet"  {
    name                = "venkat-vnet"
    address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
    location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  }
  resource  "azurerm_subnet"  "subnet"  {
    name                 = "vm-subnet"
    resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
    address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  }
  resource  "azurerm_network_interface"  "samplenic"  {
    name                = "VM-nic"
    location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    ip_configuration  {
      name                          = "internal"
      subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
      private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    }
  }
  resource  "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine"  "myvm"  {
    name                  = "venkat-vm"
    location              = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.samplenic.id]
    size                  = "Standard_B1ls"
    admin_username        = "Venkat"
    admin_password        = "Password1234!"
    os_disk  {
      name                 = "VM-osdisk"
      caching              = "ReadWrite"
      storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
    }
    source_image_reference  {
      publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
      offer     = "WindowsServer"
      sku       = "2019-Datacenter"
      version   = "latest"
    }
  }
```

**Terraform Apply:**
[image]

Reference: [Data Source: azurerm_resource_group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/resource_group)

Answer (score 0):

You can use terraform module by Azure https://github.com/Azure/terraform-azurerm-compute

```
provider  "azurerm"  {
  features  {}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name = "Existing-RG-Name" 
}
module "linuxservers" {
  source              = "Azure/compute/azurerm"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  vm_os_simple        = "UbuntuServer"
  public_ip_dns       = ["linsimplevmips"]
  vnet_subnet_id      = module.network.vnet_subnets[0]
}
```